# gtsummary: summarizing a continuous variables by two categorical variables

Tags: r, gtsummary

I am trying to summarize a continuous variable by two categorical variables as seen below. I not able to do this correctly. I wonder if there is a way to get this with the `gtsummary` package. Thank you

```
library("gtsummary")
library("tidyverse")
set.seed(123)
sex <- sample(c("Male", "Female"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
age <- rnorm(n=100, mean=20 + 4*(sex=="F"), sd=0.1)
height <- sample(c("Tall", "short"), size=100, replace=TRUE)
bmi <- rnorm(n=100, mean=10 + 4*(sex=="Female") + 2*(height=="Tall"), sd=1)

dsn <- data.frame(sex, age, bmi, height)


tab <- dsn %>% 
  dplyr::select(age, sex) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = sex) %>% 
  bold_labels() 
tab

 #Characteristic         Female, N = 43           Male, N = 57  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     age              20.00 (19.93, 20.06)   19.99 (19.94, 20.03)  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     Statistics presented: median (IQR)                            


tab1 <- dsn %>% 
  filter(height == "Tall") %>% 
  dplyr::select(bmi, sex) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = sex,
              label = list(bmi ~ "....   Tall"))
tab1

 #Characteristic         Female, N = 22           Male, N = 35  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     ....  Tall       15.54 (15.32, 16.38)   12.09 (11.53, 12.87)  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     Statistics presented: median (IQR) 

tab2 <- dsn %>% 
  filter(height == "Tall") %>% 
  dplyr::select(bmi, sex) %>% 
  tbl_summary(by = sex,
              label = list(bmi ~ "....   Short"))
tab2

 #Characteristic         Female, N = 22           Male, N = 35  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     ....  Short      15.54 (15.32, 16.38)   12.09 (11.53, 12.87)  
                   ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                     Statistics presented: median (IQR)  

# I am trying to obtain the table below
tbl_stack(
  list(tab1, tab2, tab),
  group_header = c("BMI", "", ""))

   #Group   Characteristic         Female, N = 22           Male, N = 35  
               ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 BMI     ....  Tall       15.54 (15.32, 16.38)   12.09 (11.53, 12.87)  
                         ....  Short      15.54 (15.32, 16.38)   12.09 (11.53, 12.87)  
                         age              20.00 (19.93, 20.06)   19.99 (19.94, 20.03)  
               ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                 Statistics presented: median (IQR)  

#Is there an easy way to do this using the gtsummary package
```

Comment: what I would do is create a new variable by pasting height and sex together into one variable and then use this variable in the by statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't have a function like this specifically in gtsummary. BUT, I did write one and add it to another package I've written called bstfun (GitHub only). It's a place where some gtsummary functions begin, and they may be migrated into the package at a later date.

Anyway, here's how you can get the table you're after.

```r
devtools::install_github("ddsjoberg/bstfun")
library(bstfun)

tbl <-
  trial %>%
  tbl_2way_summary(grade, trt, marker)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, @Daniel D. Sjoberg. This is great. Do you know if it is possible to add a subheader above `Age: Grade I` such as `Age by grade`.

Comment: See potential solution here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/summarizing-a-continuous-variables-by-two-categorical-variables-with-the-gtsummary-package/81937/3

Comment: Thank you. Will do