# Is there a way have a categorical variable display a continuous of different variable in gtsummary?

Tags: r, gtsummary

In the trial dataset, I would to know how to display marker level values at specific treatment levels when the summary table is by drug and strata= grade. But I am not sure how to "substitute" values. As of now the table displays the observations (n/%).

```
Here is the code and resulting table below.
```

```
    trial%>%
    select(trt,marker,stage,grade)%>%
    tbl_strata(grade,~.x%>%
    tbl_summary(by=trt,missing="no",
    label=(stage~"Marker Level (ng/mL)"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2)%>%
    modify_header(all_stat_cols() ~ "**{level}**"))
```

```
Characteristic  I   II  III
Drug A1 Drug B1 Drug A1 Drug B1 Drug A1 Drug B1
Marker Level (ng/mL)    0.96 (0.24, 1.70)   1.05 (0.29, 1.49)   0.66 (0.31, 1.23)   0.21 (0.10, 0.94)   0.84 (0.17, 1.91)   0.58 (0.35, 1.36)
Marker Level (ng/mL)                        
    T1  8 (23%) 9 (27%) 14 (44%)9 (25%) 6 (19%) 7 (21%)
    T2  8 (23%) 10 (30%)8 (25%) 9 (25%) 9 (29%) 10 (30%)
    T3  11 (31%)7 (21%) 5 (16%) 6 (17%) 6 (19%) 8 (24%)
    T4  8 (23%) 7 (21%) 5 (16%) 12 (33%)10 (32%)8 (24%)
1 Median (IQR); n (%)
```

I would like to have the 1st Marker Level row removed and the values under the 2nd marker level replaced with actual values of marker levels at T1, T2, T3, and T4. Basically the able below but with real values. I saw function that might work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64038463/gtsummary-summarizing-a-continuous-variables-by-two-categorical-variables), but I cant find the function after loading the package.

```
Characteristic  I   II  III
Drug A1 Drug B1 Drug A1 Drug B1 Drug A1 Drug B1
Marker Level (ng/mL)                        
    T1  1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4)
    T2  1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4)
    T3  1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4)
    T4  1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4) 1 (2,4)
1 Median (IQR); n (%)
```

Comment: I think you just need this function: https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/reference/tbl_continuous.html

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I have one more question I hope you can answer. How can I modify the labels T1-T4 under Marker Level suing the tbl_continuous function? Thank you!

Comment: Change them in the data frame before passing to the gtsummary function. The forcats pkg has so so so many great functions for changing levels of categorical variables